# Save Display Settings to xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, display, settings

I can configure my display setting through "System Settings > Displays"

[image: System Settings > Displays]

But I cannot save it to xorg.conf and I don't have a xorg.conf at all in /etc/X11/.

How can I save the current settings into xorg.conf?

Answer (score 7):

Those settings are saved in your home directory, not system-wide. Check out `~/.config/monitors.xml` for the file.

Comment: If I do a fresh install, can I copy this over to restore the settings? Is it ok if I added this to my backup/restore script?

Comment: Should work fine.